# Где ошибка SqlConnection UPDATE?

Tags: c#, windows, база-данных

Пишу

```
cmd3.CommandText = "UPDATE RememberAllTable SET Дата = @Дата, Событие = @Событие, Примечание = @Примечание, КогдаНапомнить = @КогдаНапомнить, Резерв1 = @Резерв1, Резерв2 = @Резерв2"
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Дата", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Дата")
```

и так перечислены все Parameters.Add. При выполнении заполняет одной строкой всю базу. Пробую по другому:

```
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Событие", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Событие
```

Аналогично - прочие. Говорит, не удалось преобразовать значение из `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` в `String`. База типа .mdf.

Comment: 1 - что значит "заполняет одной строкой всю базу"?

2 - где в вашем примере кода упоминание про DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  - не вижу его использования

3 - откуда берется у девов маразматичное на мой взляд желание именовать по русски? (ужасно режет мои мозк, когда вижу подобное)

Comment: 3 - а какая нах разница в юникоде?

Comment: Абсолютно никакой - вопрос в читабельности и подходах к оформлению кода.

Comment: 1-что значит "заполняет одной строкой всю базу"?  - буквально, при выполнении  UPDATE  строка - DataGridView  в которой сделаны изменения 
заполняет все строки базы
2- DataGridView – на форме (а то где же),   в него выводится база

Comment: 1 - обновляются все, потому что в запросе нет WHERE, которое ограничит запрос для конкретных записей

Comment: wind - спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы условие не указали, по которому надо выбрать строку, которую требуется обновить.

Comment: добавил WHERE Дата = @Дата      кажется всё заработало!                   Спасибо!

Comment: обнаружилась заковыка: при изменении в столбце, указанном как условие выборки (WHERE Дата = @Дата) кричит "нарушение параллелелизма"          Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 1):

Там может `cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Дата", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Дата")` это всё же дата а не варчар? `"Дата"` я так понимаю это переменная? Если всё же в базе это варчар сделайте `.ToString();`

Comment: Да в базе это NVarChar

Comment: Где именно сделать  .ToString ?     Если Событие .ToString    
то в ячейку прописалось следующее :             DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name=Событие, Index=1 }